# using import from statement with SystemJs

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I am trying to build up a sample code using typescript and systemjs (browser).

app.ts file :

```
import {Person,add as test} from './testLib'
```

app.js (generated by ts compiler):

```
 var testLib_1 = require('./testLib');
```

then

```
System.import('./app.js')
```

Causes 404 Error because system.js looks for **/js/testLib/** folder rather than **/js/testLib.js** file.

Any ideas why ?

My tsconfig.js:

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Causes 404 Error because system.js looks for /js/testLib/ folder rather than /js/testLib.js file

If you are using system js change `module` format to `system`

```
"module": "system",
```